# How do I work on a slice of data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to work on multiple slices of it in series. For example, if I have a dataframe with a 'person' column and some data
For each person, I want to do something to all of the rows pertaining to that person

I THOUGHT I used to be able to do this:

```
people = df['person'].unique().tolist()
for p in people:
    tmpDF = df[df['person']==p]
    // Do something to tmpDF
```

And then the original df would contain all of the changes. Pandas would give me a warning about chain assignment, but it would do the thing I wanted.

Now, it gives me a warning about changing a copy, and tells me to use `.loc`. However, that means that I need to re-slice each time I do something. I want to make the slice once in the loop and then do some stuff to the slice. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use `loc` when updating the data. For example, instead of

```
tmpDF['abc'] = 'xyz'
```

do:

```
df.loc[tmpDF.index, 'abc'] = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Seems clunkier than should be necessary, but it works. Thanks!